# expand and collapse icons

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtree

As you can see from the images below the expand and collapse icons are gray, as is the row selection highlight. This causes you to not see the **expand or collapse icon** (Note: *Not* the folder icon) when the row is highlighted, I want to have a white expand or collapse icon for the row that is selected. How can that be done?

[image]
[image]

Something else that would also be cool is, to have the expand and collapse icons completely hidden until the JTree gains focus. like windows 7's tree.

Comment: +1 for a good question, but it actually took your comment to Vicente Plata & another close look at the screen-shots for me to realize exactly what you meant!  I edited the text a little to ***emphasize*** the point.  ;)

Comment: guess no one knows, i think i will have to override the entire paint method of the tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google says -according to this post: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/DefIcons.html - :

```
// Retrieve the three icons
Icon leafIcon = new ImageIcon("leaf.gif");
Icon openIcon = new ImageIcon("open.gif");
Icon closedIcon = new ImageIcon("closed.gif");

// Create tree
JTree tree = new JTree();

// Update only one tree instance
DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer)tree.getCellRenderer();
renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon);
renderer.setClosedIcon(closedIcon);
renderer.setOpenIcon(openIcon);

// Remove the icons
renderer.setLeafIcon(null);
renderer.setClosedIcon(null);
renderer.setOpenIcon(null);

// Change defaults so that all new tree components will have new icons
UIManager.put("Tree.leafIcon", leafIcon);
UIManager.put("Tree.openIcon", openIcon);
UIManager.put("Tree.closedIcon", closedIcon);

// Create tree with new icons
tree = new JTree();

// Update row height based on new icons;
```

Certainly, I'm not sure if you can modify **only** the color of the images on-the-go. But you can always create new icons, right?

Comment: Hey, thx for replying, but those three icons (the open closed and leaf, icons) are represented as the blue folders in my images, I want to change the expand collapse icons, the gray arrows. I have successfully changed them they were always + and – signs.

Comment: They can be changed with the following code, but this however changes all the expand and collapse icons, I now only want to change the icon of the selected row.

UIManager.put("Tree.expandedIcon", new ImageIcon(FileBrowser.class.getResource("Resources/Expand.png")));
UIManager.put("Tree.collapsedIcon", new ImageIcon(FileBrowser.class.getResource("Resources/Collapse.png")));

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  You should note however to get this to work, I had to override setUI on the tree to only allow my TreeUI.

```
    private class IconTreeUI extends BasicTreeUI {

    private Icon collapseIcon = null;
    private Icon expandIcon = null;

    @Override
    public Icon getCollapsedIcon() {
        if (collapseIcon == null) {
            collapseIcon = new ImageIcon(yourCollapseImageHere);
        }
        return collapseIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public Icon getExpandedIcon() {
        if (expandIcon == null) {
            expandIcon = new ImageIcon(yourExpandImageHere);
        }
        return expandIcon;
    }}
```